# About Fourier transforms of piecewise linear functions.

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider a function $f$ which is $0$ for $x< 1$ and is say $x-1$ for $x >1$.

Consider a function $g$ which is $0$ for $x <2$ and is say $x -2$ for $x>2$.

Now using some kind of regulator one can define the Fourier transform for $f$ and $g$ and for both of them the $t^{th}$ frequency will get a term proportional to $\frac{1}{t^2}$.

From this point of view it seems that the Fourier transform of $f+g$ has its $t^{th}$ mode proportional to $\frac{1}{t^2}$.

But in reality the function $f+g$ has a line segment of equation $x-1$ for $x \in [1,2]$ and this contributes a $\frac{1}{t}$ term to the Fourier transform of the sum. The sum is $0$ for $x<1$ and is $2x-3$ for $x>2$ and these pieces will contribute $0$ and $\frac{1}{t^2}$ (respectively) proportional term in the $t^{th}$ frequency. So this $\frac{1}{t}$ term doesn't get cancelled by any other parts.

Can someone kindly help resolve this confusion?

What is the correct Fourier tranform of $f$ , $g$ and $f+g$?

Comment: Neither $f$ nor $g$ (which is a translation of $f$, by the way) are in $L^2$. Are you thinking of them as tempered distributions? Then the usual formula works: since $g$ is a translation of $f$ you also have that $\hat{g}$ is a phase shift of $\hat{f}$. In any case, the Fourier transform of the ramp function [is well known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformRampFunction.html). The apparent "contradiction" is almost certainly because you are treating a divergent integral as if it were a convergent one.

Comment: Could you kindly point to a rigorous derivation of the Fourier transform of the ramp function? What is the correct way to get the Fourier transform of the sum of two ramp functions (with different hinge points) *without* going through a rewriting of that as a piecewise linear function? (just summing the Fourier transforms of each ramp seems to give contradictions!)

Comment: Also since the ramp function is the convolution of $2$ Heavisides (at $0$) its Fourier transform should have been the product of the Fourier transforms of Heavisides which is, $\frac{1}{2} [\delta(t) - \frac{1}{\pi t}  ] $. Its not clear how its square is the Fourier transform of the Ramp at $0$ which is $\frac{i}{4\pi} \delta'(t) - \frac{1}{4\pi^2 t^2}  $.

Comment: It makes it easier if you work with $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ and use the properties: $\mathcal{F}f'=it\mathcal{F}f$ and $\mathcal{F}f(x-a)=e^{-iat}\mathcal{F}f(x)$.

Comment: You want to imagine my ramp functions as derivatives of some other function?

Comment: My ramps are like $max\{ax+b,0\}$ and then they could be written as, $max\{ax+b,0\} = (ax+b)H(x + b/a)$. Then one might say that $F(max\{ax+b,0\} ) = F(ax+b)*F(H(x + b/a ) )$ (where $*$ is the convolution). Now we need to decide what is the $F(ax+b)$. Also I am not seeing how this would help resolve the confusion I am having about the disappearing $\frac{1}{t}$ dependence when I am trying to write, $F(max\{ax+b,0\} ) + F(max\{cx+d,0\} ) = F( max\{ax+b,0\} +max\{cx+d,0\} ) $. Is this equality true?

Comment: Right! But what is the resolution to the additive expression that I wrote towards the end? Is that okay? That doesn't involve products! But something is clearly getting lost in this additive equality as evidenced by this missing $\frac{1}{t}$ piece.

Comment: Thanks! If Fourier transform remain additive even over such tempered distributions then how does one take care of this extra $\frac{1}{t}$ that pops up in the RHS?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I want to know what is the best way to compute the RHS i.e $F( max \{ ax+b,0\} + max\{ cx+d,0\} )$? This is what I really want to compute and I do not want to compute this by breaking it into linear pieces (afterall the number of linear pieces can be exponential in the number of max functions!).

Comment: I have no idea what your final comment is supposed to mean. Just take the Fourier transform of each one, for which you have an explicit formula, and add them all together. What's so hard about that?

Comment: But doing that is giving this conflict as I pointed out in my question! Fourier transform of any max function scales as $1/(frequency)^2$ (and hence this will be the scaling of the sum of Fourier transforms of max functions) whereas we know that the sum represents a piecewise linear function whose Fourier transform has $1/frequency$ terms.

Answer (score 3):

Fourier transform definition:
$$F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}f(x)dx$$

the choice $f(x)=(x-b)\theta(x-a)$ gives

$$F(t)=i(a-b)e^{iat}\frac{1}{t}-e^{iat}\frac{1}{t^2}-\pi b \delta (t)-i \pi \delta '(t)\qquad(*)$$

so the Fourier transform of $(2x-3)\theta(x-2)$, corresponding to $a=2$, $b=3/2$, does have a term proportional to $1/t$, unlike what was written in the OP. That should resolve this confusion, I hope.

---

I see the confusion remains. Let me add a bit more, in support of the expression given above. It seems we agree on the Fourier transforms of $f_1(x)=\theta(x)$ and of $f_2(x)=x\theta(x)$, with the proper distributional interpretation:

$$F_1(t)=it^{-1}+\pi\delta(t),\;\;F_2(t)=-t^{-2}-i\pi\delta'(t)$$

Direct integration gives you the Fourier transform of $f_3(x)=(x-b)\theta(a-x)\theta(x)$, which is nonzero only in the interval $0\lt x\lt a$:

$$F_3(t)=\frac{e^{i a t} (1-i a t+i b t)-i b t-1}{t^2}$$

The desired $F(t)$ is then the Fourier transform of $f(x)=f_2(x)-bf_1(x)-f_3(x)$, and linearity of the Fourier transform gives you the formula $(*)$ above, including the terms decaying as $1/t$.

---

As a curiosity, I might add that [Mathematica is confused](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125954/fourier-transform-inconsistency) about these issues as well ...

Comment: Your definition works for $f\in L^1$, but not here, where we need the distributional FT.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: actually, I think Carlo is computing the distributional FT of the function that equals to $2x-3$ when $x > 2$ and zero otherwise, and showing that this piece has a $1/t$ term (unlike what is asserted in the OP).  This would be equal to the sum of the Fourier transforms of a translated ramp function and a translated Heaviside function, which accounts for $1/t^2$ and $\delta'$ (from ramp) and $1/t$ and $\delta$ from Heaviside. The "$1/t^2$" of course needs suitable interpretation. I haven't checked the coefficients, but I assume they are done correctly.

Comment: @WillieWong: Carlo certainly did not compute the distributional FT for the simple reason that his $F$ isn't even a distribution. There has to be some principal value style regularization at $t=0$, and one has to look more carefully for that (or consult the references you gave earlier).

Comment: One could compute the integral, $FT [ (x-b)\theta (x - a) ](t) = \int_a ^\infty e^{ixt} (x-b) dx$ by using an $\epsilon$ regulator as, $lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} [\int_a ^\infty e^{i(x+i\epsilon)t} (x-b) dx  ] $ and then there is no $\frac{1}{t}$ term produced. How does one reconcile this with what Carlo is saying?

Comment: @gradstudent: Why do you want to apply makeshift fixes when this can easily be done properly. You need to take the FT as tempered distributions. The FTs of your functions, in this sense, are well known, as Willie pointed out above (and supplied references for).

Comment: Which reference you think helps?

Comment: @gradstudent: I was thinking of the link to Wolfram math world he gave above, but I hadn't looked at that. I now see that things are done in the same purely formal style that Carlo employs in his answer. The given formula on WMW doesn't make rigorous sense, of course, for the same reason: $1/t^2$ isn't even a distribution.

Comment: @gradstudent: (continued) As I've tried to point out in too many comments, the rigorous way of dealing with this involves distributions. That isn't difficult at all, it just requires some care. For example, the FT of $\theta(x)$ (Carlo's notation) in $\mathcal S'$ is $i\textrm{PV-}1/t + \pi\delta$ (the constants might be off, but the crucial detail is the principal value regularization).

Comment: @gradstudent: (still continued) All this is very classical material, so you should be able to read up on this without too much trouble. Perhaps take a look at books that discuss tempered distributions/FTs. Good luck!

Comment: @gradstudent: See perhaps this older answer of mine to a closely related questions, that might be helpful (or not): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561285/fourier-transform-of-the-regular-tempered-distribution-of-x/1562025#1562025